# Run testng tests from parent pom

Tags: maven, selenium, testng, pom.xml, parent-pom

I am trying to run TestNG Selenium tests from parent pom. When I run the command `mvn install` BUILD SUCCESSFUL message is shown, but the tests aren't run.

Following is my folder structure:

```
Parent
|----Child1
|      |---src
|      |---pom.xml
|----Child2
|      |---src
|      |---pom.xml
|      |---myTests.xml
|-pom.xml
```

When the command `mvn install` is run from Child2 folder without any changes, then the tests are run.

The Parent `pom.xml` file looks like:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <modules>
                <module>Child1</module>
                <module>Child2</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>myTests.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Child1 - `pom.xml`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example.parent<groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example.parent</groupId>
<artifactId>Child1</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
```

Child2 - `pom.xml`. This project depends on Child1

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.example.parent</groupId>
<artifactId>Child2</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>Child1</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: <suiteXmlFile>myTests.xml</suiteXmlFile> do not point to myTests.xml because myTests.xml are in different directory. Try to change it to <suiteXmlFile>Child2/myTests.xml</suiteXmlFile>

Comment: I replaced your inline code markers (`\``) with a code block. The easiest way to format a code block on SO is to paste your code, then select it and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button. This indents the whole block by an additional four spaces, instructing Stack Overflow to format it as code.

Comment: @mackowski: I have tried giving the relative path you mentioned as well `Child2/myTests.xml`, but no error was thrown. I assume that if maven cannot find the specified path, then it will throw error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the below piece of code under plugins in my parent pom and the tests ran for me.

`<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>`